# Binding a combobox with strongly typed dataset in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, combobox

I want to bind a column of a strongly typed dataset to a combobox. But the problem is i have to get only the distinct values from the column and also when a user inserts a value into that column the new value should be showned in the combobox at the same time.

And also i want to make the first row of the combobox to be unselectable..

```
cmbLabTestType.Text = "--Select--"
Dim bind As New BindingSource
bind.DataSource = daLabTest.GetData()
cmbLabTestType.DataSource = bind
cmbLabTestType.DisplayMember = "TestType"
```

how to make this column distinct values

Answer (score 0):

For removing duplicate values from ComboBox

```
For i As Int16 = 0 To Me.ComboBox1.Items.Count - 2
 For j As Int16 = Me.ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
      If Me.ComboBox1.Items(i).ToString = Me.ComboBox1.Items(j).ToString Then
           Me.ComboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(j)
      End If
 Next
Next
```

and when a user adds new data to database...
do these steps

1. Clear combobox items using `ComboBox1.Items.Clear()`
2. again get list of values from database and add them to ComboBox
3. Again call remove duplicate items function having above code in it